# call a external javascript file into blogger blog for hyperlink

Tags: javascript, blogger

actually i am creating a blogger template and i want to add some hyperlinks init so someone can't find them if they try to search it, that's why i use external javascript file to add it here it is ..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://download123.net78.net/a/b.js"></script>
```

and in the file of javascript the code is (you can also direct check the link)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[

var txt = "Hello World!";

document.write("<p>Link: " + txt.link("http://www.yoursite.com") + "</p>");

//]]>
</script>
```

and finally i didn't see the hyperlink in the blog section, would you like to tell me where is mistake, or any problem .[blogger gadgets](http://mbgadget.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var txt = "Hello Word!";
document.write("<p>Link: <a href='http://www.yoursite.com' >"+txt+"</a></p>");
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/YKbha/)

I hope it will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question. [How can I tell a dynamically inserted <script> tag to… run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973774/how-can-i-tell-a-dynamically-inserted-script-tag-to-run)

You can adapt it and set the url dynamically with an AJAX call. You could also obfuscate the link by encoding it to base 64 and then decode it when you're creating the new script element.

Overall, though I can't really think of a good reason that you would need to do this. If you are expecting dynamic data then it should be made in an AJAX call. If the script is static but you don't want it searched you should probably add it to your robots.txt.

Comment: AJAX didn't run better in blogger, actually i want to add a hyperlink in blogger so its a template and if i give this to someone he can't find the hyperlink that's the main reason i add the javascript to add hyperlink because it don't show the link its hosted in another place...... so is there any other way that i can add hyper link through including third party .... ? plzzz

Comment: I edited my comment just a minute ago. You might try the obfuscation idea and the robots.txt .

Comment: I guess it isn't clear what you really want. If you want the user to not be able to see the link to your javascript in the view source then the methods I mentioned above will work. 

If you want the script to be unavailable for inspection at all times then you're out of luck. You can't have client side code that is invisible to the client. 

If there is secret stuff in your javscript then it shouldn't be in javascript it should be in the server-side code.

Comment: Can you create a little code for me ... like above i said ,,, simple it include the hyper link, just give me two code, once where i can upload to another hosting place, and one that i add on blogger .... plzzzzzzzzz